# "Conciare per le feste": trasmutazione ossimorica del significato e storia

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin, sentences

Un modo di dire piuttosto famoso in italiano è *conciare per le feste*. Esso viene adoperato con un significato che si distanzia diametralmente da quello letterale, il quale implicherebbe un'accezione positiva di vestire a festa, quindi preparare per un evento allegro.

In realtà però, il detto sta a significare l'opposto: lo si usa per dire il contrario di quello che si esprime letteralmente. *Conciare per le feste* significa ridurre in cattivo stato, malmenare, o, figurativamente, sgridare, rimproverare.

Il Dizionario online dei modi di dire del Corriere della Sera [menziona](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/C/conciare.shtml) sbrigativamente un'origine nel fatto che fino a qualche generazione fa il volgo usava i vestiti "buoni" solo per i giorni di festa, appunto. Pur affermando la natura ironica del detto, non se ne giustifica l'uso e non si riporta una spiegazione dettagliata della sua origine e del suo sviluppo.

Chiedo se ne sapete qualcosa di più.

Comment: Molte volte si usano espressioni in senso ironico con un significato reale opposto a quello letterale: "ci sarà da divertirsi", "ne vedremo delle belle" etc. etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il *Dizionario dei modi dire della lingua italiana* di Carlo Lapucci dà anche una citazione, ma in realtà non aggiunge quasi nulla a quello che scrive Martina, su un capovolgimento ironico del vestirsi per i dì di festa. Comunque ecco tutto quello che riporta:

> **Conciare uno per le feste**
>   Conciarlo male malmenandolo o rendendogli un cattivo servizio. Rovinarlo.
>   «L'ironia è tutta popolare; e il popolo nel formarla ebbe in vista il mutare ch'ei fa di vestimenta nei giorni festivi, le quali al popolano abbelliscono la persona: quindi è bellamente ironica la frase suddetta, che viene a dire sconciamento e dissestamento dell'altrui persona» (P. L. di Vassano)

E la citazione, scopro, è dai [*Modi di dire proverbiali e motti popolari italiani, spiegati e commentati da Pico Luri di Vassano*](https://archive.org/details/modididireprove00passgoog), che era poi uno pseudonimo (e un anagramma) di Ludovico Passarini.

Lapucci accosta il modo di dire, per significato e, direi, per intento ironico, a “servire uno di barba e parrucca”, dove il senso è sempre quello di “abbellire”, usato con aspra ironia.